# Android: how to switch button's pressed state programmatically?

Tags: android, button, android-drawable

I have a button with 2 distinct pictures for pressed and released state. How do I switch the state programmatically?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[`View.setPressed(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPressed%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 1):

this can be done by using custom drawable backgound inside our ImageButton

`buttonSelector.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> <item  android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_disabled" android:state_enabled="false" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" />
```

put this @drawable/buttonSelector.xml code  inside the background of your Image Button xml code

```
<ImageButton
   android:id="@+id/demoBtn"
   android:background="@drawable/buttonSelector"
   android:layout_width="70dp"
   android:layout_height="70dp"
   android:src="@drawable/btndefaultImage"/>
```

In your Mainactivity you can set button state as pressed or in default state by using below line

```
demoBtn.setSelected(true);//used to maintain button as selected/pressed
demoBtn.setSelected(false);//used to maintain button as unseleced/default
```

Comment: I think you should use: "android:state_activated" instead. "android:state_selected" seems more for D-pad navigaton stuff.